# Insert parent element ID into dynamic element

Tags: jquery

Markup:

```
<iframe id="portal">
    <div id="callout-1" class="callout">
    </div>

    <div id="callout-2" class="callout">
    </div>
</iframe>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page-portal').load(function(){
        $('#portal').contents().find('.callout')
        .append('<div class="edit-image" id="edit-image-1">Edit This Area</div>');
    });
});
```

This code dynamically inserts a `div class="edit-image"` into each `div class="callout"`

What I want to do is retreive the ID (numeric portion) from `div class="callout"` and dynamically insert it into the ID of `div class="edit-image"`

I am having trouble with this, can anyone help?

Comment: when are you guys gonna start using the data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of Javascript. It should look something like this

```
$('#portal').find('.callout').each(function(k,v) {
    id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    //take out the id of element

    temp = id.split("-"); 
    //split the string based on "-"

    idnum = temp[1]; 
    //take the second part of split i.e the integer part

    $(this).append('<div class="edit-image" id="edit-image-'+idnum+'">Edit This Area</div>'); 
    //then finally use it
});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaA6w/)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the id of an element with

```
var id     = $("selektor").attr("id"),
    number = parseInt(id.split('-')[1]);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

In your case, you have to iterate over all .callout's in your document, then parse the id as above and then insert the new element with the correct id.